# regex in app script a quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non fixed width

Tags: javascript, php, regex, google-apps-script

I using regex in app script and has problem to select numbers the code is bellow.

String from website is:

`<fin-streamer class="C($primaryColor) Fz(24px) Fw(b)" data-symbol="ALLY" data-test="qsp-price" data-field="postMarketPrice" data-trend="none" data-pricehint="2" value="7,32.541" active="">31.74</fin-streamer>`

Regular expression to take just the price 31.74 is:

`/(?<=<fin-streamer class="C\(\$primaryColor\) Fz\(24px\) Fw\(b\)" data-symbol="ALLY" data-test="qsp-price" data-field="postMarketPrice" data-trend="none" data-pricehint="2" value="\d+" active="">)(.*?)(?=<\/fin-streamer>)/gi`

I go to find this number 31.74.
this is my link of regex: https://regex101.com/r/9SdMcF/3

in this section

`/value="\d+"`

I add + but give me error: a quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non fixed width.
remember this value (value="7,32.541") is changed dynamically

Comment: Surely [`(?:value=")[-+]?(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)(?:")`](https://regex101.com/r/8ZcCsQ/1) would be enough here?

Comment: but why if there more that one dot . or more than one , of this symbol

Comment: and this get "value=" . I want to take numbers from "active="">31.74</fin-streamer>"

Comment: It's not clear why this question has the tags other than [tag:regex] and [tag:javascript]. If they are really relevant please add a [mcve].

Comment: I will be suprised if the value attribute is different...

Answer (score 0):

To get the number just before `</fin-streamer>`, use the regex `([\d.,]+)<\/fin-streamer>`.

To get both the number just before `</fin-streamer>` and the preceding number in the `value="31.74"` bit, use this regex:

`value="([\d.,]+).*?([\d.,]+)<\/fin-streamer>`

To use the regex in Apps Script, use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), like this:

```js
  const matches = myHtmlString.match(/value="([\d.,]+).*?([\d.,]+)<\/fin-streamer>/);
  if (!matches) {
    console.log('no matches');
    return;
  }
  const firstMatch = matches[1];
  const secondMatch = matches[2];
```

Comment: I do what you thing work: https://regex101.com/r/AAf6So/1 can you check that. why I using all this regex because I have a webe page has a lot of codes

Comment: Bro can you see my regex: https://regex101.com/r/9SdMcF/2 . in this case the Match 1 and Group 1 is the same 31.74 all is great now but if I change the value="45.23" is the Test string nothing work why. I add in regular expression value="([\d.]+).*?([\d.]+)" like you tell me but nothing work. just need to change the value="" in regular expression .

Comment: I add more explain in code you see above

Comment: If your data uses comma `,` as thousands separator, you need to include that in the regex. See the regex in the answer. It matches the sample data you show.

Comment: I' beginner in coding if you has the answer you can create new code in  regex101.com

Comment: regex101.com does not deal with code but regexes. You can paste the regex in the answer there if you want.